# (PUT) endpoint not working as expected for Tick entries

Tags: api, rest

Using the PUT request to update Tick entries is not working as expected. Using the following: PUT /entries/235.json will update the entry from the parameters passed

GitHub link: https://github.com/tick/tick-api/blob/master/sections/entries.md#update-entry

Currently receiving a 400 Bad Request ([screenshot](https://share.getcloudapp.com/X6uQ6wl5))

I tried the GET request to confirm authorization is working as expected, and received a 200

Comment: Well your request body says that you're missing parameters.

Comment: You're absolutely right, @Evert. 

I've attempted to use every parameter and a combination of parameters without success. I wasn't sure if anyone else had run into this issue as the documentation doesn't look to clearly note which parameters: [GitHub](https://github.com/tick/tick-api/blob/master/sections/entries.md#update-entry)

I've attempted to use the "hours" and "billed" parameters without success: [screenshot](https://share.getcloudapp.com/wbuQpZnr)

Comment: Usually properties are sent in a json body, not the query string. I would give that a shot.